# llvm error: linking error to libLTO.so

Tags: llvm

During compilation of `llvm` I get following error:

```
llvm[2]: ======= Finished Linking Debug+Asserts Executable llvm-config
llvm[2]: Installing Debug+Asserts /usr/local/bin/llvm-config
make[2]: Leaving directory `/usr/bin/tools/llvm-config'
make[2]: Entering directory `/usr/bin/tools/lto'
llvm[2]: Compiling LTODisassembler.cpp for Debug+Asserts build (PIC)
llvm[2]: Compiling lto.cpp for Debug+Asserts build (PIC)
llvm[2]: Linking Debug+Asserts Shared Library libLTO.so
collect2: ld terminated with signal 9 [Killed]
make[2]: *** [/usr/bin/Debug+Asserts/lib/libLTO.so] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/usr/bin/tools/lto'
make[1]: *** [install] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/bin/tools'
make: *** [install] Error 1
```

I do configure `llvm` by giving path of `gcc` & `g++` compilers.
I don't get any error during configuration; but during build same error persist with `clang` also. I am using `Ubntu-12.10` 32 bit.

Comment: see my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59436978/992406

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, so to solve this problem, I referred to llvm.org and during configuration added few options as follows:
    `sudo ./configure CC="/usr/bin/gcc" CXX="/usr/bin/g++" --enable-optimization --enable-jit --enable-debug-runtime --enable-targets=all`

And I ran a build as `SuperUser`.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same error using Ubuntu 13.04 (arch: x86_64). The following error

> collect2: ld terminated with signal 9 [Killed]

was an issue with memory usage. I was indeed using a Koding.com cloud VM with 1GB RAM.

I tried the compilation on my laptop as a normal user and the compilation finished without any issues. I used:

> $ ./configure
>
> $ make -j4

Comment: What leads you to believe it was a memory issue?

Comment: changing to ld.gold may help. `cmake -DLLVM_USE_LINKER=gold`
  https://lists.llvm.org/pipermail/llvm-dev/2017-August/116440.html