# Building X86 LLVM on Ubuntu

Tags: cmake, llvm

I'm using VMware workstation 15 to run Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS,with 40GB of allocated disk space. I'm trying to build the X86 LLVM using the steps described in https://clang.llvm.org/get_started.html.
gcc and g++ latest versions are installed.
Steps used on a clean copy(after installing cmake, git, and essentials packages):

```
git clone https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project.git
cd llvm-project
mkdir build
cd build
cmake -DLLVM_ENABLE_PROJECTS=clang -G "Unix Makefiles" ../llvm
make
```

After an hour and a half i get this message(clipboard isn't working):
[image]

Anyone knows what's this about?

Comment: How much RAM do you have allocated?

Comment: The default, i believe it's 2GB

Comment: Did you see the answers to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20137827/3987854)? I would try using more memory (perhaps 4GB) to rule out that issue as a potential cause...

Comment: It was a memory issue as answered in the above question. Thank you.